# how to access https sites in java

Tags: java, https, httpurlconnection

I have to access an https site through my java code. But it returns 401 response. I included my code below.

```
try {        
 URL u = new URL(url);
 HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
 http.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
 http.connect();

 String userpassword = "HP:M0lveau";
 byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(userpassword.getBytes());
 String encodedAuthorization = new String(encoded);

 http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
 InputStream is = http.getInputStream();

 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 String line = null;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
 }
 return stringBuilder.toString();

} catch (IOException ioe) {
 logger.debug("fetchDataFromServer:IOException");
 return null;
}
```

Please help as early as possible.. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.. This is my code.

```
private static String fetchDataFromServer() throws HttpException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

        logger.trace("__ENTERING CluemasterData::fetchDataFromServer()");

        try {
            URL u = new URL("https://....");
            HttpsURLConnection http = (HttpsURLConnection)u.openConnection();
            Authenticator.setDefault( new MyAuthenticator() );
            http.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            http.setRequestMethod("GET");
            http.connect();

            InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();    
        }
        catch (HttpException he) {

            return null;
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {

            return null;
        }

    }
```

The class MyAuthenticator

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator
   {
   /**
   * Called when password authorization is needed.
   * @return The PasswordAuthentication collected from the
   * user, or null if none is provided.
   */
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
      {
      return new PasswordAuthentication ( "username", "password".toCharArray() );
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

**401 response means that the request requires user authentication**. LOOK [here for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026260/java-how-to-use-urlconnection-to-post-request-with-authorization)

Have something like

```
public static String userNamePasswordBase64(String username, String password)
{
    return "Basic " + base64Encode (username + ":" + password);
}

static public String base64Encode(String s)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Base64OutputStream out = new Base64OutputStream(bout);
    try
    {
        out.write(s.getBytes());
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
return bout.toString();
}
```

and then use

```
http.setRequestProperty ("Authorization",userNamePasswordBase64("HP","M01veau"));
http.connect();
```

Also check manually that these credentials are working fine on the given url.
Also [See this great tutorial](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0084.html)

Comment: I think you meant setting username and password. But  I have set it.

Comment: String userpassword = "HP:M0lveau";
 byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(userpassword.getBytes());
 String encodedAuthorization = new String(encoded);

 http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);

Comment: Thanks for your help..I tried it. But couldnt. I also used HttpsURLConnection. Is any other mistakes in my code?

Comment: @Sarika: did your credentials(usename/passwd) work when u accessed this site normally through your browser?? what is the url?

Comment: @Sarika : see the new function base64Encode() also in edited answer. Maybe it will help.see this also http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/146/page5.html

Comment: May I know the package for Base64OutputStream?

Comment: @sARIKA : As Maurice mentioned "Try to set the Authorization header before the call to connect()" like i have in my answer. The package is package gnu.inet.mime.base64 . check this - http://www.koders.com/java/fid2C8F058DD15AB1913D9D427DE5C10853CD711FB7.aspx?s=base64#L2 and this http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/jss/javadoc/org/mozilla/jss/util/Base64OutputStream.html

Comment: @ayush : I think the problem is not with the https. Because I have got response for the host site. So the problem may be with the authentication part. Am I correct?

Comment: @Sarika : what do u mean by "response for host site"? how and what response did you get? The authentication code i gave above is correct assuming your username and password are correct.and very imp - ARE YOUR USERNAME/PASSWORD WORKING FINE WHEN YOU ACCESS THIS URL NORMALLY THROUGH A BROWSER??

Comment: Sorry! I meant this - "https://www.cluemaster.com". The response is its page source(html). MY USERNAME AND PASSWORD WORKING FINE WHEN I ACCESS THIS URL NORMALLY THROUGH A BROWSER. I tried with your code. But coudnt complete it since I didnt know how to include package gnu.inet.mime.base64 in my package.

Comment: @ayush : I got it. I have added the code below.. Thanks a lot for your helping mind.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the Authorization header before the call to connect()