# Java Android GPS send coordinates

Tags: java, android, gps, coordinates

I've got many Android devices and I want to create an application that will be able to send the GPS coordinates and some id of the device to a server created on a PC. what is the fastest and easiest way to do do that ? I tried to find some telnet or java spring rest template but couldn't find a decent tutorial.

please help

Comment: What does 'telent or java spring rest template' have to do with an android app that sends coordinates to another server?

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps

1) Getting the GPS coordinates

There are a multitude of examples on how to do this; look into LocationListener and read the [Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) section of the docs.

2) Sending this data to a server

You will probably use an HTTP Post to accomplish this.  See e.g. this [Android HTTP Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670911/android-http-communication) post and [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) class.

As far as getting a unique ID, you can use the suggestion from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) and use Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID