# What exactly does URLConnection.setDoOutput() affect?

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

There's `setDoOutput()` in `URLConnection`. According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput%28boolean%29) I should

> Set the DoOutput flag to true if you intend to use the URL connection for output, false if not.

Now I'm facing [exactly this problem](http://webdiary.com/tag/httpurlconnection/) - the Java runtime converts the request to `POST` once `setDoOutput(true)` is called and the server only responds to `GET` requests. I want to understand what happens if I remove that `setDoOutput(true)` from the code.

What exactly will this affect? Suppose I set it to `false` - what can I do now and what can't I do now? Will I be able to perform `GET` requests? What is "output" in context of this method?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You need to set it to true if you want to send (*output*) a request body, for example with POST or PUT requests. With GET, you do not usually send a body, so you do not need it.

Sending the request body itself is done via the connection's output stream:

```
conn.getOutputStream().write(someBytes);
```

Comment: What if I'm downloading an image ?

Comment: Downloading? Or uploading?

Answer (score 34):

`setDoOutput(true)` is used for `POST` and `PUT` requests. If it is `false` then it is for using `GET` requests.

Comment: ok, how can I then force this connection to do PUT since server on the other side is accepting only PUT requests, not POST... ?

Comment: What if I'm downloading an image ?

Comment: Why is it named `setDoOutput`? Not a very intuitive name

Answer (score 3):

Adding a comment, if you have a long lasting connection and you send both GETs and POSTs, this is what I do:

```
if (doGet) {    // some boolean
    con.setDoOutput(false); // reset any previous setting, if con is long lasting
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
}
else {
    con.setDoOutput(true);  // reset any previous setting, if con is long lasting
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
}
```

And to avoid making the connection long lasting, close it each time.

```
if (doClose)    // some boolean
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

con.connect();              // force connect request
```

Comment: Ya hit on a pet peeve of mine there sonny.  One call to setDoOutput: `con.setDoOutput(!doGet);`, rather than two with true/false value inside an if.    The worst is if (foo) return true else return false, but this still treads on that particular toe.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setDoOutput( boolean dooutput )
```

It takes a value as the parameter and sets this value of the `doOutput` field for this URLConnection to the specified value.

A URL connection can be used for input and/or output. Set the DoOutput flag to true if you intend to use the URL connection for output, false if not. The default is false.

Comment: I've read that in the documentation before asking. The reason I'm asking is I don't get the implications of those.

Comment: If you want to write to a connection object you got to set the serDoOutput true