# Zip file download in android

Tags: android, download

I have an app to download zip file content from drop box (which is publicly shared path). i wrote download code using HttpURLConnection but its not working as intended and instead is downloading a small portion (after download zip file showing 31 kb but its original size is 3mb). i am attching my code. please help me to solve this.

```
         URL url = new URL("drop box public share url");
        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        urlConnection.connect();
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"/download/sample.zip");
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        int downloadedSize = 0;
        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; 
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                onProgressUpdate(downloadedSize, totalSize);

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();
        inputStream.close();
```

Comment: You may wish to retrieve the value of the `Content-length` response header and read until you got that many bytes.

Comment: if etienne suggestion doesn't work, you'll have to see if 'if-range' works to retrieve the data is several parts.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the method call:

```
setDoOuput(true);
```

makes the request a POST (see
[What exactly does URLConnection.setDoOutput() affect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587913/what-exactly-does-urlconnection-setdooutput-affect))

Removing it seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use plain URLConnection not HttpURLConnection. And see the output.