# How to make an HTTP POST URL connection?

Tags: java

I am accessing a web service by an HTTP POST method as below:

But the response contains nothing. I was expecting a JSON string here. Are JSON read in a different way?

Comment: I think the best answer you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the type as [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)  instead of URLConnection. It allows to specify HTTP method.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using a HttpUtlConnection or HTTPClient is going to make you life easier, but have a look at setDoOutput

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput(boolean)

and

[What exactly does URLConnection.setDoOutput() affect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587913/what-exactly-does-urlconnection-setdooutput-affect)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
URLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

make `connection` an instance of `HttpURLConnection`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Shammiz answer

Without cast Make use of  [URLConnection.html#setDoOutput(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput%28boolean%29)

> A URL connection can be used for input and/or output. Set the DoOutput flag to true if you intend to use the URL connection for output, false if not. The default is false.

Passing `true`, triggers `post`.