# How to build the URL for sentiment140 request?

Tags: java

How to build the URL for sentiment140 request? For the following JSON data,

```
{"data": [{"text": "I love Titanic."}, 
         {"text": "I hate Titanic."}]}
```

I have built the following URLs:

`http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson?appid=me@gmail.com&text=I+love+Titanic.`

and

`http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson?appid=me@gmail.com&text=I+hate+Titanic.`

Both POST requests return a blank. Any suggestions would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an HTTP POST URL connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527739/how-to-make-an-http-post-url-connection)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are POST'ing?  The above urls look like GETs.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL</h1>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [API documentation](http://help.sentiment140.com/api) you are supposed to pass the JSON data as the request body of a `POST` method, not as URL parameters.

So it should look something like this:

```
String data = "{\"data\": [{\"text\": \"I love Titanic.\"}, {\"text\": \"I hate Titanic.\"}]}";

URL url = new URL("http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson?appid=me@gmail.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

// write the request body
connection.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF8"));

// get the response and read it
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
```