# java.io.FileNotFoundException, but php file exists

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to upload a file to a server, but when I try to open the connection it fails and gives a FileNotFoundException, while the file is there. I my browser on my desktop it executes the php. This is my code:

```
  URL url = new URL("http://www.test.com/files/upload_file.php");
  connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

And this the error:

```
 12-07 14:43:01.337: W/System.err(19473): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.test.com/files/upload_file.php
12-07 14:43:01.347: W/System.err(19473):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
```

Comment: Have you tried another url (google for ex.)?

Comment: Is this php file a local file or one hosted on a remote server?

Comment: It's on a remote server. But I get a different error when I use google. So there might be something going on with my server. Thanks

Comment: It is strange, I'm able to connect through my browser on the phone, but not like above.

Answer (score 2):

I had your same problem and even if much time has gone since you made the question, this could be useful for the googlers.

Well, all I've done is adding this string:

```
connection.setDoOutput(false);
```

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587913/what-exactly-does-urlconnection-setdooutput-affect)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out in the end that the error came from and not from :

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

Changing into:

```
InputStream is = connection.getErrorStream();
```

fixed the error

Comment: hi, can you explain more detail about this..I have the same issue..so changing the code like above will solve this issue?