# 405 Error when sending HTTP request throw JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, http

I try to send http request and get the result with a Java code

this is the Server side:

```
public class Testws {
@GET
    @Path("/test/{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Integer getAssets(@PathParam("id") int id){
        }
}
```

And this is the Client side:

```
URL url = new URL("http://xxx/route/test/1");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();
final int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

when i run this java code i got an 405 status code but when i put the link (http://xxx/route/test/1) directly in the browser it works fine i got 200 as a response code.
How can i fix this ?

Comment: Why do you do `setDoOutput(true)` when you want a GET request?

Comment: Try `connection.sendGet();`

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies.
@Fran: connection.sendGet(); dont work
@Thilo: you are right the problem was `setDoOutput(true)`  i deleted it and it works fine now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error means that you query the server with the wrong `HTTP` method.

What you paste in your browser will be sent as `GET` method.

Your code doesn't use `GET`, so to force an HTTP method, use [HttpConnection.setRequestMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod(java.lang.String))

Alternatively, `setDoOutput(true)` won't make you use `GET`, see this topic :
[What exactly does URLConnection.setDoOutput() affect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587913/what-exactly-does-urlconnection-setdooutput-affect).

Remove this line and you will use the default HTTP method, which is `GET`.

> public void setRequestMethod(String method)
>                         throws ProtocolException
>
> Set the method for the URL request, one of: GET POST HEAD OPTIONS PUT DELETE TRACE are legal,
>   subject to protocol restrictions. **The default method is GET**.

Comment: Thanks! i have deleted `setDoOutput(true)` and it works fine now.