# Node JS server hosted on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, httpurlconnection

I am having a problem with my connection to Elastic Beanstalk server. I am running a server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with a simple call as followed:

```
app.get('/WhatIsCool?', function (req, res) {
    res.send("You are cool!!!")
})
```

and on the Java side I have

```
public String testing() {
    try {
        URL http = new URL(urladdress + "/WhatIsCool");
        HttpURLConnection openCon = (HttpURLConnection) http.openConnection();
        System.out.println(http);
        openCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
        openCon.setDoOutput(true);
        openCon.setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000);
        openCon.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
        System.out.println("Well I got this far.");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openCon.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Can I get this far?");
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("What is cool? " + inputLine);
            return inputLine;
        }
        br.close();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return "Error: " + e1;
    }
}
```

but for some reason I keep getting an error on right after the line that says "Well I go this far" I am unsure what I am doing wrong I have tried so many different things online but none of them seem to work. I should also mention that when I run it locally it works just fine.

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Try removing the `setDoOutput(true)` part. Also, what happens when you paste the content of the `http` String in a browser ? see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587913/what-exactly-does-urlconnection-setdooutput-affect

Comment: It works just fine when i past to a browser

Comment: Just tried removing the `setDoOutput(true)` and it still didnt work