# REST web service - sending post request with xml from JSP

Tags: xml, jsp, rest

I have a JSP file in which I have an entity class - I want to add the user to the database. I have a REST web service with POST method that consumes application/xml. I guess, I have to parse the data to XML and invoke post method, but how to send this xml data to rest with this call ? I know only how to invoke GET methods, but how to call for example post or delete methods that needs some parameters?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two challenges: generating XML (not parsing, parsing is converting from XML, not to) and POSTing it.

The first problem is rather simple. You can use various libraries, from [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb), through [dom](/questions/tagged/dom) to manual crafting of XML using `StringBuilder` (not advised).

You can send POST in plain Java, see: [Java: how to use UrlConnection to post request with authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026260) There are also special libraries, like [httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient).

BTW do **not**: call web services, access database directly, start threads, open files... in JSP. At least use servlets and leave JSP for representation.