# setRequestProperty in java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

The documentation [here](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says that `setRequestProperty` sets the general request property.

So suppose I have the following code snippet showing the usage of `setRequestProperty` as follows:

```
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("datetime", dateTimeString);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("authorization", authorization);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConn.setDoInput(true); // Triggers POST
```

Q1: Does `accept` need to have an uppercase `A` here? Similarly, for `authorization`, does it need to have an uppercase `A` as well? The reason I am asking this is because I have seen many post where people have been using `authorization` as say for example `conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString);`. This is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026260/java-how-to-use-urlconnection-to-post-request-with-authorization/2165000#2165000).

Q2. Since I have lot of `setRequestProperty` property defined above, does this means that, a URL contains all of these properties? Are there any other properties that exists besides the one I have used above?

Comment: setDoInput(true) does not trigger POST.

Comment: @EJP But it's required for `POST`, am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A1: HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5), request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. **Field names are case-insensitive**.

A2: These variables will be in the HTTP request header. If you want URL contains these parameters, you need to append them on the URL:

```
http://www.google.com?bar=far&boo=foo
```