# Convert Curl to Java equivalent

Tags: java, curl, httpurlconnection

I'm working with `New Relic REST API` for the first time, I have a curl command:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/appid/metrics/data.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:myApiKey' -i \
     -d 'names[]=EndUser/WebTransaction/WebTransaction/JSP/index.jsp'
```

I want to send this command in a java servlet and get a JSON object from the response ready for parsing, What is the best solution?

HttpURLConnection?

Apache httpclient?

I've tried a few different solutions, but nothing has worked so far and most examples I could find are using the depreciated DefaultHttpClient

Here is an example of one of my attempts:

```
 String url = "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications.json";
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Api-Key", "myApiKey");
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        JSONObject names =new JSONObject();

        try {
            names.put("names[]=", "EndUser/WebTransaction/WebTransaction/JSP/index.jsp");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(names.toString());
```

**Edit**

I've modified the code a bit, it's working now thanks.

```
String names = "names[]=EndUser/WebTransaction/WebTransaction/JSP/index.jsp";
String url = "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/myAppId/metrics/data.json";
String line;

try (PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter()) {

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-Api-Key", "myApiKey");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(names);
            wr.flush();


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.println(HTML_START + "<h2> NewRelic JSON Response:</h2><h3>" + line + "</h3>" + HTML_END);
            }
            wr.close();
            reader.close();
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest using a librari like Apache HttpComponent or Unirest that simplifies this greatly.

Comment: What advantages does  Apache HttpComponent have?

Comment: It's an API easier to code, understand and maintain. Unirest is built on top of Http Components and it's even easier to connect through http.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I think I'll modify my code to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl -d` sends whatever you specify without formatting it in any way. Just send the string `names[]=EndUser/...` in the OutputStream, without wrapping it in a JSONObject. Don't forget to call `wr.flush()` after writing the string. And of course, after that, you need to get the `InputStream` and start reading from it (I only mention this because it's not in your snippet).

Comment: And see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026260/java-how-to-use-urlconnection-to-post-request-with-authorization) for details.