# simulate curl -d request in HTTP

Tags: java, http, curl, flags

I want to simulate a request of the form `curl -d "param = value" "http://ip:port?key1=value1&key2=value2"` using the REST API Testing, but unfortunately I do not know how. More details about the `-d` flag can be found [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d).

If I use `POST` for the method type then I get a `405` error and if I use `GET` for the method type then I get a `404` error. From the command line the command works perfectly and I am able to receive the answer, but I do not know how to adjust the snippet `-d "param = value"` in a HTTP request.

I really appreciate any kind of help !!!

Comment: Simulate `curl -d` in **which language or environment**? Also, post here your attempts that are not producing the expected results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !!! The detailed request looks like this `curl -d "input.string = a b c a b see" 'localhost:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=spark.jobserver.WordCountExample'` and is taken from [spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver). I would like to simulate `curl -d` in **Java** but as a HTTP request. More specifically, I do not know how to add the parameter `"input.string = a b c a b see"` in the message.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33310075/convert-curl-to-java-equivalent) post very helpful. Thank you again for your support !!!