# Curl transfer to java

Tags: java, curl

how can I transfer this Curl command to Java http post:

> curl --insecure -XPOST -H 'Authorization: XXXXX' -F 'Name=test name' -F 'text=test content123456' 'http://serverhost.com/api/index.php?action=send'

Thanks guys.

I've already try,but I think there may have a better way.

```java
URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(reqBody);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2026299/2814332) might help you.

Comment: Well this is wrong: `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");`  You are not using `Curl` to send the request.   But why don't tell us what is causing you difficulties.  Right now, this question comes across as "please write the rest for me".

Comment: Thank guys.I already change my method.Pls see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys.I already fixed it. Code example down bleow:
URL url = new URL(urlStr);

conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);

conn.setReadTimeout(30000);

conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setDoInput(true);

conn.setUseCaches(false);

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

//advance api
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authorization)) {

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
```

}

conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",

```
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.2.6)");
```

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",

```
    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
```

out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

// text
if (textMap != null) {

```
StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

Iterator iter = textMap.entrySet().iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();

    String inputName = (String) entry.getKey();

    String inputValue = (String) entry.getValue();

    if (inputValue == null) {

        continue;

    }

    strBuf.append("\r\n").append("--").append(BOUNDARY)

            .append("\r\n");

    strBuf.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""

            + inputName + "\"\r\n\r\n");

    strBuf.append(inputValue);

    logger.info(inputName + "," + inputValue);

}

out.write(strBuf.toString().getBytes());
```

}